# How to get unlimited argument without parameter limit

Tags: php

```
   function test(){

   }
 test(58,1,"world","hello");
```

How can Use this argument test() function  parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Use [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

```
<?php

function test(){
  print_r(func_get_args());
}
test(58,1,"world","hello");
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 58
    [1] => 1
    [2] => world
    [3] => hello
)
```

Comment: Thanks It's Very helpful for me.